# class DisplayManager: vector<string>

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I'm working on an assignment for my C++ programming class.  The assignment is basically to take code given to us and fill it in to make a working, low level, text editor.  Problem is, I've never seen this syntax before.  If I knew what it were called, I could find information about it, I'm sure. It might even be in my textbook, I just haven't been able to find it...

Anyway, if anyone could point me in the right direction for learning about this type of class, I'd appreciate it greatly.

```
class DisplayManager: vector<string>
```

(A display is a vector of strings called "rows". Each line of the document may occupy one or more rows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called inheritance. [Please have a look here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)

Your `DisplayManager` class inherits from `vector<string>`. That means, it is essentially the same as `vector<string>`, plus the changes you make in the class body. However, since you did not add the `public` keyword, users of the class will not be able to access the members it inherited from `vector`.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I can't believe I didn't recognize that. I've used inheritance with my own classes, never like this though. Thanks so much for clearing up my dumb question!